# Highest possible sound quality recording for a live stream youtube

Tags: desktop-recording

I am trying to be able to record the best quality audio from a daily live stream on youtube (only internal sound, no microphone).

Until now I have been using simple screen recorder and using a 2x2pixel rectangle recording and then opening the file with audiacity, removing some long pauses and exporting it to mp3 but not sure that this is the best way.

If that is the best way, what audio codec (right now vorbis) and bit rate (now 128) should I use? As it is a youtube livestream, does it makes sense to have a higher bit rate then 128? Should I choose better settings while exporting to mp3 from audiacity?

Thank you so much as I have been doing this since a year and actually the sound is probably not the best...

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

“Best” is highly subjective, but one way to accomplish this is with `youtube-dl` and the `--extract-audio` option:

```
youtube-dl -x --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 {YouTube Link}
```

This will download the audio component in as high a quality as YouTube will permit.

If you would like to do this for a number of videos all at once, you can queue up an entire play list for extraction:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" {playlist URL}
```

From here, you can continue to pull the audio into Audacity for some tweaking if you wish to remove gaps, hisses, or other audio blemishes.

If you do not already have `youtube-dl` on your machine, you can install it via the Snap store or the command line like this:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl
```

Comment: Thank you Matigo for your answer, is this possible for a livestream video that is only accessible during the lifestream? The video don't stay once the lifestream is finished...